# Rendering mathjax content with data loaded from ajax response

Tags: ajax, mathjax, will-paginate

In case like pagination gems like [will_paginate][1]

content that was loaded from ajax doesn't render MathJax symbols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So something like this would fix.

```
$( document ).ajaxSuccess(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
   let url = new URL(event.target.URL);
   let params = new URLSearchParams(url.search.slice(1));
   if (params.get('page') != null) {
      MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);
   }
});
```

In my case it pase will_paginate which could be identified by a param - **page**

It may be just a url in your case so checking like

```
event.target.URL == 'something'
```

should do good.